# How to set video format of camera in OpenCV ? CAP_PROP_FOURCC didn't work

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

I'm using a camera which support 'MJPG' and 'YUY2'.
I found its default format is 'YUY2' but I want to use 'MJPG', so I used the code below.

```
VideoCapture cap(0);
cap.set(CAP_PROP_FOURCC, CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'));
cout << CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G') << endl;
cout << cap.get(CAP_PROP_FOURCC) << endl;
```

But it came out with below:

```
1196444237
8.44715e+08
```

The first of is the FOURCC of 'MJPG' and the second is 'YUY2'.
In a world,set CAP_PROP_FOURCC didn't work.

So, How to set video format of camera in OpenCV ?

Answer (score 0):

To set the video format in OpenCV you need to use VideoWriter which makes the decoding of your parameter as follows:

```
cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M','J','P','G'));
```